# Repair or replace a mail slot on an exterior stucco wall

Tags: steel, stucco, mailbox

Our home in LA County was built in 1939 with a thru-wall mail box with a chute into our dining room. The mail slot (the opening) and chute (embedded in the wall) are held by pins that broke off leaving an exposed exterior wall.  I would like to get the mail slot fixed or replaced without having to break open the stucco wall or purchase a wall mailbox as I like the original style. However, I'm having difficulties locating replacement parts. Any assistance?
Thank you
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How about a picture or two so we know what you're talking about.

Comment: Hello @jack, Here are the pictures of the mail slot and exposed exterior wall.

Comment: the mail slot looks ok ... the mail slot cover is the problem

Comment: drill holes where the hinge pins are (were), carefully tap some threads ... screw in machine screws that are longer than the tab width ... file off exposed threads on the screws so that they are more like pins

Comment: Thank you @Jsotola that's an idea. I'll look into this route.

Comment: try brass or stainless steel screws

Answer (score 0):

Two thinks come to mind. Drill small holes in those two tabs where the pins used to be. Screw some self tapping screws into the holes and then cut off the screw heads leaving enough of the screws to act as pins.

You could also web search "vintage mail slot covers" to look for something similar or an upgrade.

I have no business interest in any of these sites.